# convert arduino sensor data become integral in visual c++

Tags: c++, arduino, serial-port

I want to send my ultrasonic data from Arduino to visual c++ and use the data as integral. I able to send the data using serial communication but the data is incorrect. Sometime, the same data has been repeated or separated (like 255 become 2 55). I able to read the data in string from (with other code) but fail in integral from which can be map in matrix form. Can anyone give me some suggestion so that my ultrasonic distance data can be read and become image (100 x 100 distance data) in the end.

C++ code

```
Serial arduino("COM3");    // adjust as needed

char incomingData[256] = "";    // don't forget to pre-allocate memory

int dataLength = 3;

int readResult = 0;

while (arduino.IsConnected())

{ 

readResult = arduino.ReadData(incomingData, dataLength);

incomingData[readResult] = 0;

serialRXint = atoi(incomingData); //to convert char serial data from Arduino into a usable integer   

serialRXint << endl;

cout << endl<<serialRXint << endl;

Sleep(5);

}
```

Comment: You should also provide the *arduino* code.

Comment: You need some synchronisation. E.g. send a newline after each number and convert to a number only at the end of a line. Different than file IO, Serial takes time and you do not always have a complete message available.

Comment: In my Arduino code, I already send the new line as well. So, do I still need to create a new line in my c++ code ?

Comment: On the receive side, I'd read byte by byte until I get a '\n' char. 
Then replace that by '\0' (redundant, if you do not want to print it) and apply atoi to it. and reset buffer positions, of course.

Comment: Depends on what Serial::ReadData is doing exactly. (Seems to come from : `http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/CPPWindows` ? )
What about .net SerialPort instead ?

Comment: The code is mainly from the Arduino playground and I would like to modify from that.
For the replacement part, I still not that clear. Is it mean I need to add some code before atoi so that my code can read it in integral. For example, my Arduino data is 255\n, I need to ask c++ there to recognise  the \n ?